# How to treat the units of measure when taking a derivative?

Tags: units, differentiation, calculus

I've had a doubt for a long time: when I'm taking the derivative, of a function for example, how should I treat the units of measurement? For example, if I'm taking the derivative of:

$$S\,[{\rm m}]=S_{0}\,[{\rm m}]+v\,[{\rm m}\,{\rm s}^{-1}]\,t\,[{\rm s}]+\frac{1}{2}a\,[{\rm m}\,{\rm s}^{-2}]\,t^{2}\,[{\rm s}^{2}]$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From a dimensional analysis standpoint, a derivative behaves like a ratio. You divide the dimensions by whatever units the independent variable has. Does this help; is this what you're asking?

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimal I as thinking that we could treat the units as constants or something like that....

Comment: @WaynerKlën if you follow your example and are taking the derivative with respect to *t*, then you'll see what Rod Vance is telling you is correct. Each term on the right will need to be divided by [s] to make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the purposes of dimensions (units), you can treat a derivative like a division. So when you apply $\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}$ to a function you divide the dimensions of the function by a unit of time. In your example I get:

$$\frac{{\rm d}S}{{\rm d}t}\left[{\rm m}\,{\rm s}^{-1}\right] = v \left[{\rm m}\,{\rm s}^{-1}\right] + a\,\left[{\rm m}\,{\rm s}^{-2}\right]\,t\,\left[{\rm s}\right]$$

which of course makes sense, in terms of units.